# В последней строке прижать блоки к левому краю

Tags: вёрстка, flexbox

Пытаюсь сделать такое размещение блоков, но в последней линии на разных разрешениях блоки не соответстуют размерам других блоков и не прижаты к левому краю. Думал добавить пустых блоков с `flex-grow: 1;` и `flex-basis: 150px`, в таком случае работает нормально. Как можно обойтись без пустых блоков? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

article {

 flex-basis: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px; 
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
  <article>6</article>
  <article>7</article>
  <article>8</article>
  <article>9</article>
  <article>10</article>
  <article>11</article>
  <article>12</article>
  <article>13</article>
  <article>14</article>
  <article>15</article>
</section>
```

Comment: По сути мой  вариант с пустыми блоки выглядит точно как у автора этого https://codepen.io/dalgard/pen/Dbnus. Но есть ли возможность сделать без пустых блоков?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее:

1. У блоков убрать flex-basis и flex-grow.
2. Контейнеру задать максимальную и минимальную ширины.
3. Ширину самих блоков рассчитывать с помощью calc, исходя из того, сколько блоков должно поместиться в строке в различных диапазонах ширин экрана (через медиа-запросы).

В примере ниже предполагается, что у страницы ширина может меняться от 320px до 1200px, ширина контейнера составляет 95% ширины страницы, и при следующих максимальных ширинах экрана в контейнер помещается блоков:

- 1200px - 6 блоков;
- 1000px - 5 блоков;
- 850px - 4 блока;
- 700px - 3 блока;
- 520px - 2 блока;
- 350px - 1 блок.

P.S. У вас в коде предусмотрены отступы блоков от контейнера справа и снизу по 10px, это здесь сохранено.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

article {

  width: calc((100% - 60px) / 6);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
/*  flex-grow: 1;*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  article {
    width: calc((100% - 50px) / 5);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  article {
    width: calc((100% - 40px) / 4);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  article {
    width: calc((100% - 30px) / 3);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  article {
    width: calc((100% - 20px) / 2);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
  article {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
  <article>6</article>
  <article>7</article>
  <article>8</article>
  <article>9</article>
  <article>10</article>
  <article>11</article>
  <article>12</article>
  <article>13</article>
  <article>14</article>
  <article>15</article>
</section>
```

Comment: maridu - Сделал похоже как Вы предлагаете только поделил на 5 градаций 20%, 25%, 33.3%, 50%, 100%. И сам section имеет ширину всегда 100%.

Comment: @Shperung - Если section будет иметь ширину 100% от ширины _страницы_, на маленьких экранах (меньше максимальной ширины страницы) блоки будут прилипать к краям экрана, поэтому для таких случаев обычно предусматривают отступы слева и справа, чтобы воспринималось лучше.